# Need some guidance about creating classes

Tags: c#, class

Basically I have class called as `Category`. `Category` might be food,Sports,Entertainment,Commuity,Work.

Now I have a page called as `CreateNewProduct`. Here we are having the fields like Name,Kind, Brand etc.
Here the field visibility,control enable,disable, change the label text, validations are varying based on the category we select from the dropdown list. There are possibilities for the categories to be added in future. 
What would be best idea to handle the visibility, control disable, change the label text and validation.

Comment: You need to post some code please so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: As new categories can be added, it seems to me that a data-driven list is more appropriate than an `enum`.  Given that, as others said, your object is `Product`, and `Category` is a property of the `Product` and not (IMO) a class.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a `class`? Can't you use an `enum` instead? Then have it as a property in your `Product` class.

```
public enum Category
{
    Food,
    Sports,
    Entertainment,
    Commuity,
    Work
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category ProductCategory { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The only downside I see to this is that you'd probably need switch statements all over the code to determine what behavior, validation, etc. should apply... which I believe is was the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: Here the control has to set as visible for one category and disable for another category and validation might be different for another categories. How can we solve that situation?

Comment: And if tomorrow some categories added then the same page would be fill up with lot of code.  What I am thinking is simply create a table for product and have its business properties like 'Text' it should show in the page and business properties that ties with the product. Here i am getting into the controversy of Single Page for single item, or same page for many items. If its single page many items, then it would be difficult if many categories come.

Answer (score 0):

*Category* probably should be an [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) (*Category*) and your class should be called "Product" and one of it's properties should be of type *Category*.

Other properties you add to the Product class could help you drive visibility, disable, etc. Validation might be a bit more complex and you would need to expand on that.

Comment: Hmm, I'm wondering if this would be a good use of inheritance. You could potentially have a sub-class for each product category that has the appropriate overridden validation functions?

Comment: Not sure I totally get it (yet), but your approach sounds like it's more scalable.

Comment: If new categories are added, then we need to create a another class.I am thinking off to move everything to the DB.